# skip user loading screen in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I only have 1 user profile on my computer, is there any way to tell windows 7 to skip the user selection screen, and just boot straight into the OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this (I know it says Vista in the link, but it's supposed to work for Win7 as well):

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/make-windows-vista-log-on-automatically/